# C/C++ Class Not Declare in Scope: Secondary Class Instantiation from Primary Class Contructor

Tags: c++, arduino

Am doing my final year project in control theory stuffs.

Therefore need lots transfer functions (TF), so i wrote a class for it and it works fine; on its own.

```
class TF
{
  private:
    //variables
  public:
    TF (double * Numerator, double * Denominator)
    {
      // initialising stuffs     
    }
    float compute(double input)
    {
      // core stuff going on here
      return answer;
    }
};
```

But i need to design controllers which makes use of lots of TFs, so decided to clean up my code and use another class.

```
class Ctrl
{
  public:
  friend class TF;
  int b1, b2;
    Ctrl (int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
    {
      /* 
        b1 = a4; b2 = a5;
        Num1 = F1(a1); Den1 = F2(a1);
        .
        some kind of functions to generate numerators and denominators (arrays)
        .
        Num3 = F1(a3); Den1 = F2(a3);
      */
      TF Block1(Num1, Den1);
      TF Block2(Num2, Den2);
      TF Block3(Num3, Den3);
    }
    float compute(double input1, float input2)
    {
      float ans1 = Block1.compute(input1) + b1;
      float ans2 = b2 * Block2.compute(input2);
      float ans3 = Block3.compute(ans1 + ans2);
      return ans3;
    }
};
```

so now somewhere in the main program initialise my controller with:

```
Ctrl myController(1,2,3,4,5);
```

I receive the following errors:

```
In member function 'float Ctrl::compute()': 'Block1/2/3' was not declared in this scope
```

Could you people tell me whats wrong and how to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.
And for info am implementing the code on the Arduino Platform.

Comment: Please use the "C/C++" language tag for questions about this language. Until such a tag (or language) exists, your code is C++ **only**! C is a different language.

Comment: And stack overflow is no debugging service. See [ask]

Comment: not related to your problem, but imho a class name like `TF` is way too cryptic. Why not call it `TransferFunction` (and `Controller` instead of `Ctrl`) ?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this code:

```
Ctrl (int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
{
  /* 
    b1 = a4; b2 = a5;
    Num1 = F1(a1); Den1 = F2(a1);
    .
    some kind of functions to generate numerators and denominators (arrays)
    .
    Num3 = F1(a3); Den1 = F2(a3);
  */
  TF Block1(Num1, Den1);
  TF Block2(Num2, Den2);
  TF Block3(Num3, Den3);
}
```

Here `Block1`, `Block2`, and `Block3` are local variables inside the constructor. As soon as the constructor ends, they are destroyed again.

If they are to persist, they have to be member variables, like `b1` and `b2`.